# How to multiple event handles and pass data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach multiple events to a single element. But I want to attach different data to each event. The way to attach multiple events in jQuery is as follows:

```
 $("div.test").on({
     click: this.clickEventCalled,
     mouseenter: this.mouseEnterEventCalled
     mouseleave: this.mouseLeaveEventCalled
 });
```

But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 $("div.test").on("click", { name: "Karl" }, clickEventCalled);
```

And I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this than:

```
 var self = this;
 $("div.test").on({
     click: function(event){
         self.clickEventCalled(event,{name:"Karl"})
     },
     mouseenter: function(event){
         self.mouseEnterEventCalled(event,{name:"Ben"})
     },
     mouseleave: function(event){
         self.mouseLeaveEventCalled(event,{name:"Ken"})
     }
 });
```

Comment: Nope, to add a parameter to the functions, you'll need to call them with the parenthesis, and to do that, you need the extra function call, so that is probably the easiest and most proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("div.test").on("click", { name: "Karl" }, clickEventCalled)
             .on("mouseenter", { name: "Ben" }, mouseEnterEventCalled)
             .on("mouseleave", { name: "Ken" }, mouseLeaveEventCalled);
});
```